# c double field access, why would you have struct->field_1->field_2

Tags: c

This a quick question, It is probably duplicate but i could it found it,

Can someone explain me what is happening in this line

```
  BlockPrefix_t *makeFreeBlock(void *addr, size_t size) { 
  BlockPrefix_t *p = addr;
  void *limitAddr = addr + size;
  BlockSuffix_t *s = limitAddr - align8(sizeof(BlockSuffix_t));
  p->suffix = s;
  s->prefix = p;
  p->allocated = 0;
  return p;
}
```

This is the code:

```
BlockSuffix_t *newBlock = (void *)r->suffix + requiredSize;
newBlock->prefix = r;
BlockPrefix_t *temp = (void *)newBlock + suffixSize;
temp->suffix = (void *)nextRegion->suffix;
temp->suffix->prefix = temp;
```

I do not understand why the double access?

Comment: Please post the struct definition so we can help.

Comment: It would be clearer if you posted the `struct` definitions.

Comment: Thank you, @rcmgleite I add the code

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the BlockPrefix_t is something like this:

```
typedef struct BlockPrefix_t {
    struct BlockPrefix_t* prefix;
    struct BlockPrefix_t* suffix;
} BlockPrefix_t;
```

If it is, you are accessing the prefix of the suffix of your temp variable and assigning temp to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the line like that:

```
(temp->suffix)->prefix = temp.
```

You are assigning the value of the field "prefix" of the data structure pointed by "temp->suffix" to temp itself.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be linking the free block in a doubly linked list, accessible from the beginning of the block and from the end of the block.  This is probably used to coalesce free blocks incrementally.

Posting the definitions for `BlockPrefix_t` and `BlockSuffix_t` would help confirm this hypothesis.